# Use a static or a non static class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I got a class that I made static, but is it a bad option? Should it be a non static class?

I want to set two values in my class.

Is there any chance when you give properties values that there will be some kind of conflict when setting them and when getting them? If another user have the same target.

I got a page that calling this class.
One user hits the page and this happens.

1. Set the properties for the calculation
2. Run the void to calculate two properties
3. "Maybe some other functions runs and take some time"
4. Get the value of the two properties

But what if another user hits the page and sets other values and make either the first user's value incorrect. I guess that's possible?

Some other options I thought of is to either

- Send all properties into the void as arguments and return a new class with my two values I need. (Not store them as a static property that could be changed by another user before it got used).
- Create a new class with the properties (perhaps called BreakTime). Send that into the void as one argument. Return it, calculated.
- Or you tell me what the best option is! :)

Here how it looks:

```
public static class BreakTimeCalculator
{
    public static int BreakFromSec { get; private set; }
    public static int BreakUntilSec { get; private set; }
    public static int CustomBreakSec { get; set; }
    public static int FromSec { get; set; }
    public static int UntilSec { get; set; }
    public static int Equlizer { get; set; }

    public static void CalculateBreakFromAndBreakeUntil()
    {
        var taskLength = UntilSec - FromSec;
        var middleOfTask = FromSec + (taskLength / 2);
        var secondsToMoveLeft = middleOfTask % 300;
        var amountEqualizers = CustomBreakSec / Equlizer;
        var fiftyFifty = amountEqualizers % 2 == 0;
        var leftSideEqualizers = fiftyFifty ? amountEqualizers / 2 : (amountEqualizers / 2) + 1;

        BreakFromSec = middleOfTask - secondsToMoveLeft - (leftSideEqualizers * Equlizer);
        BreakUntilSec = BreakFromSec + CustomBreakSec;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply make a class static if you HAVE to, not if it is possible. I doubt that is the case here. Usually this should rarely happen (e.g. on classes that hold extension-methods).

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I'd go for the rule "make a class static, if you can. If you have state, then you can't".

Comment: @DavidArno Well, you can provide (one single) state to static objects I guess, however its quite bad design. However with "when you can" I ment when its syntactically correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never create static state unless you really, really have to as you'll set yourself up for a fall if you do. You make testing harder and you make the likelihood of a thread conflict (as you describe) happening much higher.

If you must set state in a class and then invoke methods, rather than just passing the values as parameters to the method, make it a non-static class. Also, you should preferably pass the values in via the constructor, rather than using properties.

Having said that, my approach to your problem would be to create a POCO to hold the result data and have a static method to do the calculation. Using C# 6 syntax, this would look like:

```
public class BreakTimeResult
{
    public BreakTimeResult(int breakFromSec, int breakUntilSec)
    {
        BreakFromSec = breakFromSec;
        BreakUntilSec = breakUntilSec;
    }

    public int BreakFromSec { get; }
    public int BreakUntilSec { get; }
}


public static class BreakTimeCalculator
{
    public static BreakTimeResult CalculateBreakFromAndBreakeUntil(int customBreakSec,
                                                                   int fromSec,
                                                                   int untilSec,
                                                                   int equlizer)
    {
        var taskLength = untilSec - fromSec;
        var middleOfTask = fromSec + (taskLength / 2);
        var secondsToMoveLeft = middleOfTask % 300;
        var amountEqualizers = customBreakSec / equlizer;
        var fiftyFifty = amountEqualizers % 2 == 0;
        var leftSideEqualizers = fiftyFifty 
            ? amountEqualizers / 2 
            : (amountEqualizers / 2) + 1;

        var breakFromSec = middleOfTask - secondsToMoveLeft - (leftSideEqualizers * equlizer);
        var breakUntilSec = breakFromSec + customBreakSec;
        return new BreakTimeResult(breakFromSec, breakUntilSec);
    }
}
```